# Как сделать порядок в сообщениях android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

Обновил студию до 3.1 и теперь нет окна `messages` коротое всегда появлялось если возникали ошибки при компиляции

И там очень все красиво было и порядок был, что удобно можно было увидеть и понять в чем ошибка.

Теперь согласно этому ответу на стаке(самый последний)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27726216/how-to-show-android-studios-messages-window?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Он говорит о том, что терерь эта возможность доступна из вкладки `build` , но там помимо сообщений об ошибкая я получаю и все `warning` и все это написано как то в одну строчку, что становиться тяжеловато понять, что к чему

Как можно сделать как было? Или как можно настроить то, что хочешь там видеть(Своего рода фильтр)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При возникновении какой то ошибки компиляции справа открывается новое окно, в котором можно узнать подробную информацию касательно ошибок. При нажатии на отмеченные красными знаками разделы компиляции\сборки, можно в том же окне справа узнать, в чем проблема на конкретном этапе:

[image: scrn]

Ошибки компиляции отображаются в нижней секции (на скриншоте *Kotlin compiler*). Здесь можно узнать, в чем именно проблема и перейти к строке в коде, который вызвал эту проблему (на скриншоте: не определена переменная `currentSpinnerPosition` и лог указывает на два места в классе, где эта неопределенная переменная используется):

[image: scrn]

На мой взгляд так даже удобнее, потому что появилась какая то структура, а не все в одной портянке. В любом случае сделать как было видимо нельзя и настроить фильтр тоже нет возможности, может быть она появится в будущих версиях (особенно если писать фидбэки)

Comment: Это не совесем так. Вот допустим такая ситуация, есть интерфейс который имплементируют несколько классов, вот я добавляю новый метод и нажимаю ран, было удобно раньше, что в логе у меня есть ссылка с ошибкой на каждый класс который должен имплементировать этот интерфейс(включая новый добавленый метод) , то сейчас я действительно получаю то, что у вас на скрине, какие то ошибки  `TaskExecutionExeption` и все. Ни ссылок на классы в которых ошибки, ни собственно нормального описания(class has to implement interface)